# Passing a list to partialview, BeginCollectionItem()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, begincollectionitem

I want to pass a list to PartialView that has BeginCollectionItem(). Here is the code,

`InquiryOrderViewModel`

```
public class InquiryOrderViewModel
{
    public InquiryOrder InquiryOrder { get; set; }
    public List<InquiryOrderDetail> InquiryOrderDetails { get; set; }
    public List<InquiryComponentDetail> InquiryComponentDetails { get; set; }        
}
```

`InquiryComponentDetail` model

```
public class InquiryComponentDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int InquiryComponentDetailId { get; set; }

    public int DesignCodeId { get; set; }

    public int QualityReferenceId { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }

    public int Length { get; set; }

    public int GscmComp { get; set; }

    public int Wastage { get; set; }

    public int TotalYarn { get; set; }

    public virtual DesignCodeQltyRef DesignCodeQltyRef { get; set; }

}
```

`InquiryOrderIndex` View and the Script to render multiple items at once

```
@model eKnittingData.InquiryOrderViewModel 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "InquiryOrder"))
{
..........
<div id="cmpDts">
  @foreach (var item in Model.InquiryComponentDetails)
    {

    }
</div>
..........
}

<script>
        var prev;
        $(document).on('focus', '.class03', function () {
            prev = $(this).val();
        }).on('change', '.class03', function () {
            if (prev != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ComponentDts", "InquiryOrder")', // dont hard code your url's
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { DesignCdId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.cmpCls').last().replaceWith(data);
                    }
                }); 
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ComponentDts", "InquiryOrder")', // dont hard code your url's
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { DesignCdId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
                    success: function (data) {
                            $(".class03 option[value='']").remove();
                            $('#cmpDts').append(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
```

The `_DetailEditorRow` PartialView which gives ddls with `class03` and in main view where it got appended.(This is just to show you what is `class03`)

```
@model eKnittingData.InquiryOrderDetail
@using eKnitting.Helpers

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("InquiryOrderDetails"))
{
<div class="editorRow">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.ComponentId, (SelectList)ViewBag.CompList, "Select", new { Class = "class02" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.DesignCodeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.DCodeList, "Select", new { Class = "class03" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.NoOfParts, new { Class = "class01" })
    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
</div>
}

and in main view it got appended to 

<div id="editorRows">         
            @foreach (var item in Model.InquiryOrderDetails)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_DetailEditorRow", item);
            }           
    </div>
```

`_ComponentDetails` PartialView to render items(a list has been passed at once)

```
@model List<eKnittingData.InquiryComponentDetail>
@using eKnitting.Helpers

<div class="cmpCls">
@foreach(var icd in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("InquiryComponentDetails"))
    {
    <div class="innerCmpCls">
        @Html.DisplayFor(a => icd.DesignCodeId)
        @Html.DisplayFor(a => icd.QualityReferenceId)            
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => icd.Height, new { Class="clsHeight clsSameHL"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => icd.Length, new { Class = "clsLength clsSameHL" }) 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => icd.GscmComp, new { Class = "clsGscmComp clsSameHL" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(A => icd.Wastage, new { Class = "clsWastage" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Fds", "View", new { id = icd.QualityReferenceId }, new { @class = "myLink", data_id = icd.QualityReferenceId })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => icd.TotalYarn, new { Class = "clsTotalYarn" })
        <br>
        <div class="popFds"></div>
    </div>
    }
}
</div>
```

ActionResult that Passes a list at once and returns the PartialView

```
    public ActionResult ComponentDts(int DesignCdId)
    {
        var objContext = new KnittingdbContext();
        var QltyRefList = objContext.DesignCodeQltyRefs.Where(a=>a.DesignCodeId==DesignCdId).ToList();

        var iocdList = new List<InquiryComponentDetail>();

        foreach(DesignCodeQltyRef dcqr in QltyRefList)
        {
            iocdList.Add(new InquiryComponentDetail { 
                DesignCodeId=dcqr.DesignCodeId,
                QualityReferenceId=dcqr.QltyRefId
            });
        }
        return PartialView("_ComponentDetails", iocdList);
    }
```

ActionResult for `GET`

```
        var objContext = new KnittingdbContext();

        var newIovm = new InquiryOrderViewModel();
        var newIo = new InquiryOrder();
        var iocdL = new List<InquiryComponentDetail>();

        newIovm.InquiryOrder = newIo;
        newIovm.InquiryComponentDetails = iocdL;

        return View(newIovm);
```

ActionResult for `POST`

```
public ActionResult Save(InquiryOrderViewModel inquiryOrderViewModel)
{
    .........
}
```

When user selects an item from a dropdownlist(`class03`), the items related to that item are rendered to the view  using the PartialView(`_ComponentDetails'`) and get appended. Then user selects another item from another ddl(`class03`), the related items are rendered and appended after earlier appended ones. User can go on like this.

Rendering and appending items works fine. But for the PostBack even though i get the number of items in the list correctly(I checked it by putting a break point on `POST` ActionResult ) all items content show null values. Pls guide me in the correct way for achieving this. All help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A few things that don't make sense - `@foreach (var item in Model.InquiryComponentDetails) { Html.RenderPartial("_ComponentDetails",item); }` is passing an instance of `InquiryComponentDetail` to the `_ComponentDetails.cshtml` partial view, but that view expects `List<InquiryComponentDetail>` so that code would throw an exception. Your script is referencing elements with `class="class03"` but your code does not show any elements with that class name - i.e. you have not shown us the correct code.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thanks for replying :) I updated the question and now  you can see where does this `class03` come from. It is the `Class` of ddls.And also i removed `RenderPartial` inside `foreach` since im not rendering an initial item at the beginning. If there is any unclear thing pls let me know..

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Hope i have provided information such that you can get a clear idea. But if it's still not clear pls tell me. Im still struggling with this question

Comment: Still confused. `InquiryOrderViewModel` does not contain a collection property of type `InquiryOrderDetail` so its unclear what its for. But if your properties are not not binding, you need to show your model for `InquiryComponentDetail` (first thing to check is do you properties have getters and setters)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, yes there is a list of `InquiryOrderDetail` in viewmodel. I removed it from the question as i thought it is not relevant to question. Now i added it again. In `InquiryComponentDetail` model every property has getters and setters. Shall i update the question to show `InquiryComponentDetail` model also?

Comment: Yes, show the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95161/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-isuru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_ComponentDetails` view is generating form controls that have name attributes that look like (where `###` is a `Guid`)

```cs
name="InquiryComponentDetail[###].icd.Height"
```

which does not match your model because typeof `InquiryComponentDetail` does not contain a property named `icd`. In order to bind to your model, your `name` attribute would need

```cs
name="InquiryComponentDetail[###].Height"
```

To generate the correct html, you will need 2 partials

`_ComponentDetailsList.cshtml` (this will be called by the `ComponentDts()` method using `return PartialView("_ComponentDetailsList", iocdList);`)

```cs
@model List<eKnittingData.InquiryComponentDetail>
<div class="cmpCls">
  @foreach(var item in Model)
  {
    Html.RenderPartial("_ComponentDetails", item);
  }
</div>
```

`_ComponentDetails.cshtml`

```cs
@model eKnittingData.InquiryComponentDetail
using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("InquiryComponentDetails"))
{
  <div class="innerCmpCls">
    @Html.DisplayFor(a => a.DesignCodeId)
    @Html.DisplayFor(a => a.QualityReferenceId)            
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Height, new { @class="clsHeight clsSameHL"}) // use @class, not Class
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Length, new { Class = "clsLength clsSameHL" }) 
    ....
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked! you spent lot of time for me. Thank you very much :) Lastly could you pls tell me how to set the `id` of this after the above amendments `@Html.ActionLink("Fds", "View", new { id = icd.QualityReferenceId }, new { @class = "myLink", data_id = icd.QualityReferenceId })` in `_ComponentDetails.cshtml` view?

Comment: should be just `new { id = Model.QualityReferenceId }` and `data_id = Model.QualityReferenceId `

Comment: Ok.. Thank you very much :)